# How to tick checkbox of listview checkbox listcell programmatically in javafx

Tags: javafx

[This is my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbX1z.png)

I am using mongodb.
For other types which are string , int , etc i can easily store and read data from db. But for list view i have a document which has two keys: title and completed.
The completed stores boolean value of tick(checkbox listcell).
But i cannot find a way such that:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbX1z.png) to save the tick(tick or unticked) in db.
[2] to manually set the tick during app startup(i use db to prevent data loss after closing app)

```
    asList.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String arg) {
            return new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        }

    }));
```

// Here asList is ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selectedStateCallback` maps each element in the list view to a `BooleanProperty` that is bidirectionally bound to the selected state of the check box. So to select or unselect the check box, you need to set that `BooleanProperty` to true or false, respectively.

In your code, you don't keep any reference at all to the `BooleanProperty` you create for this, so you have no opportunity to change its state.

The best approach is to create a class to represent your document, having `title` and `completed` properties. Represent the `completed` property with a `BooleanProperty`, and supply that property from the `selectedStateCallback`. Make the `ListView` a `ListView<Document>`, and then you just have to set the `completed` state of the `Document` and the check box will update accordingly.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class CheckBoxListCellExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<Document> listView = new ListView<>();

        StringConverter<Document> converter = new StringConverter<Document>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Document document) {
                return document.getTitle();
            }

            // not actually used by CheckBoxListCell
            @Override
            public Document fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }

        };

        listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(Document::completedProperty, converter));

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20 ; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add(new Document("Document "+i, i%2==0));
        }

        Button markAllCompleted = new Button("Mark All Completed");
        markAllCompleted.setOnAction(e -> {
            for (Document doc : listView.getItems()) {
                doc.setCompleted(true);
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(listView);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(markAllCompleted, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(markAllCompleted, new Insets(10));
        root.setBottom(markAllCompleted);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Document {
        private final StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final BooleanProperty completed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        public Document(String title, boolean completed) {
            setTitle(title);
            setCompleted(completed);
        }

        public final StringProperty titleProperty() {
            return this.title;
        }


        public final String getTitle() {
            return this.titleProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setTitle(final String title) {
            this.titleProperty().set(title);
        }


        public final BooleanProperty completedProperty() {
            return this.completed;
        }


        public final boolean isCompleted() {
            return this.completedProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setCompleted(final boolean completed) {
            this.completedProperty().set(completed);
        }



    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```